# MVC Razor helper does not exist in current context

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, visual-studio-2012

I have created a custom razor helper in my MVC4 Web application that I need to be usable in all of my views.

In all of my view pages, I can't seem to use my custom helper. VS2012 doesn't just see it.

How Can I resolve this please ?

**EDIT**: It actually works when I run the page, it's just VS that doesn't see it.

Here is my helper which is located in Helpers.cshtml within my AppCode folder.

```
@helper TextBox(string title, string id, string placeholder, bool required){    
<ul>
    <li>
        <label for="@id">@title</label>
    </li>
    <li>
        <input type="text" name="this" class="@if (@required) {<text>required</text>}" minlength="2" id="@id" placeholder="@placeholder" />
    </li>
</ul>
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If it is [razor helper(using @helper syntax)](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2011/05/12/asp-net-mvc-3-and-the-helper-syntax-within-razor.aspx), you should define it in view placed within \App_Code

> We can accomplish this by saving our @helper methods within
>   .cshtml/.vbhtml files that are placed within a \App_Code directory
>   that you create at the root of a project. For example, below I
>   created a “ScottGu.cshtml” file within the \App_Code folder, and
>   defined two separate helper methods within the file (you can have any
>   number of helper methods within each file):

And if it is more traditional html helper, you should reference it, by adding record to `namespaces` element of `<system.web.webPages.razor>` defined in `~\Views\Web.Config`. If you want to use it only in singe view, you could add `@using` directive on top of view.

Comment: VisualStudio seems to create some 'gobbledygook' class name that seems to look like my helper, but this still doesn't allow me access to any of the helper methods.

Comment: You should show the code then, because way described in my answer works

Comment: You cannot call your helper like @Html.TextBox as that is razor helper, not html helper. You should call it as Darin Dimitrov suggested

Comment: If it works in one environment and yells in another (i.e. production server), try this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13597285/484108

Answer (score 10):

Restart Visual Studio

Clean and rebuild alone was not enough but the steps that worked for me were:

1. Clean solution
2. Restart Visual Studio (2012)
3. Rebuild solution

After those steps, the Visual Studio Intellisense picked it up again.

Comment: **TIP** If the folder was created, you really should Restart Visual Studio

Answer (score 6):

**Try to build/rebuild the project** (if your helper is in the `App_Code` folder).

Then VS will recognize the helper.

Comment: It was the solution to me. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

In any view you could call your custom Razor helper like this:

```
@Helpers.TextBox("some title", "someid", "default value", false)
```

This assumes that your helper is defined inside `~/App_Code/Helpers.cshtml`.

Comment: To be honest, I did this exactly before coming on stackoverflow. It actually works when I run the page, however, visual studio doesn't seem to recognise the helper. It comes out with a squiggly line underneath the call

Comment: Oh, you should have mentioned that. Razor Intellisense is far from perfect in Visual Studio. We can hope that they will improve it in future versions.